# My Function returns "[object Promise]" as result(after timeout). But when the function is used, the console is already logging the result (steamID) JS

Tags: javascript, function, discord, discord.js

I tried it without the timeout, without transfering the steamID into a string (both "Cannot send an empty message")an some more. But I haven't gotten any further for like 30 minutes.

(vanityURL = input)

My Function(The API is completly working):

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const botconfig = require("../botconfig.json")

async function getSteamID(vanityURL) {

    const response = await fetch(`https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/ResolveVanityURL/v1/?key=${botconfig.steamapikey}&vanityurl=${vanityURL}`);
    const data = await response.json();

    const listDataRaw = JSON.stringify(data);
    const listData = listDataRaw.toString();

    var steamID = listData.replace(/{"response":{"steamid":"|","success":1}}/g, "") // Filter
    console.log(steamID)

    return steamID;
}

module.exports = { getSteamID }
```

My test command:

```
const getSteamInfo = require('../functions/getSteamInfo');

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    var vanityURL = args.join(' ')


    const rawSteamID = getSteamInfo.getSteamID(vanityURL);

    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
    let steamID = rawSteamID.toString();
    message.channel.send(steamID)



};

module.exports.command = {
    name: `test`
}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: You have an `async` function, so you have to `await` its result ...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to `await` your call to `getSteamInfo.getSteamID`.

(You also forgot to `await` the call to `message.channel.send` so right now any errors thrown by it would turn into an unhandled rejection.)

```js
const getSteamInfo = require('../functions/getSteamInfo');

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    const vanityURL = args.join(' ')

    const rawSteamID = await getSteamInfo.getSteamID(vanityURL)
    //                 ^^^^^

    const steamID = rawSteamID.toString() // not sure this is even needed...?
    await message.channel.send(steamID)
    //^^^
}

module.exports.command = {
    name: `test`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put "await"
const rawSteamID = await getSteamInfo.getSteamID(vanityURL);

and see it is working